# Connect Bluetooth permanently _ Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I am looking for a Linux tool(s) to setup permanent connection to Bluetooth device.

My OS is Ubuntu Linux .
As of now I have to perform too many "click this" to actually detect and connect to the device. And it goes away on next boot.

I know that powered Bluetooth device sends a message ( on boot )  and I should be able to detect and react to such message. Since Bluetooth is a part of the OS kernel this should be feasible.

Any constructive, leading to solution,  ( excluding AI bot ) suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot answer your question. Two things I would try:  (1) update the firmware (Kernel) on Ubuntu (for Bluetooth updates); and (2) try a different Bluetooth device (break the problem in half).

Comment: Try the methods from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334386/how-to-set-up-automatic-connection-of-bluetooth-headset).